# Java compiler warning caused by generics when saving ArrayLists

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, objectoutputstream

This seems like a pretty standard problem, but it's just so simple I don't know what to do about it. From what I've read elsewhere on SO, this is caused by Generics when ArrayLists are initialized without specifying parameters. I also know that the warning does not come up when I comment out `ArrayList<Integer> p = (ArrayList<Integer>)is.readObject();`, so I'm pretty sure there is a generics safety issue with the compiler by me trying to cast the `Object` to an `ArrayList<Integer>`. How can I save the `ArrayList` without causing this?

Here's the code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class FileTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String fileName = "fred.txt";
        ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        a.add(2);
        a.add(3);
        a.add(4);
        try
        {
            ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName));
            os.writeObject(a);
            os.close();
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e){e.printStackTrace();}
        catch(IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}
        try
        {
            ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName));
            ArrayList<Integer> p = (ArrayList<Integer>)is.readObject();
            //for(int i : p) System.out.println(i);
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e){e.printStackTrace();}
        catch(IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}
        catch(ClassNotFoundException e){e.printStackTrace();}
    }
}
```

Comment: Well there you go, haha. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm pretty sure there is a generics safety issue with the compiler by me trying to cast the Object to an ArrayList.

Not just a Generics safety issue, a *type* safety issue. You are assuming that the next thing is an `ArrayList` and that you can safely use it as an `ArrayList<Integer>.`

> How can I save the ArrayList without causing this?

Your problem isn't with saving it, it is with getting it back. Add `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` or whatever it is before the declaration.

Comment: +1 I think you have pretty much nailed it